# How to Put Matrix in a Look and store values?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to put one matrix in a look and want to get values of that matrix after that loop and want to store it. Example:

```
N =10;
C=eye(N);
P=[.1 .2 .3];
for k=1:3
    Rp=C;
    for i=1:N
        if(rand < P(1,k))
            Rp(i,:) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

From the above function it is clear that i will get 3 Rp matrix as i have 3 values of P. How to store the values of all these 3 Rp? Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you trying to do? It is very unclear

Comment: P is my error. C is one 10x10 matrix. Rp is the matrix after passing the error through channel. After considering P, the Rp matrix will be a different matrix than C as some packets in C will get affected by the error. As i have three P values so i want to get three different Rp matrix. Can you suggest me now @MZimmerman6

Comment: So what I am understanding is that you want all three `Rp` matrices stored at the end of each loop.

Comment: Yes.. you are right. Because i need to use those Rp matrix further in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, just simply store the results at the end of the main loop into a cell array.

```
N=10;
C=eye(N);
p=[.1 .2 .3];
RpMats = cell(1,numel(p));
for k=1:numel(p)
    Rp=C;
    for i=1:N
        if(rand < p(1,k))
            Rp(i,:) = 0;
        end
    end
    RpMats{k} = Rp;
end
```

`RpMats` is a cell array where index 1 corresponds with the probability at index 1.